# How can Community approve a suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

[This edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/2534) was approved by Community. I thought that edit suggestions required someone with high reputation to go in and manually either approve or reject in order to be resolved.

How did this happen?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86630/13992

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click on "improve", the suggested edit will be approved by the community user, and your own improvements will be added as a second edit under your own name.

So, the approval here still was done by a regular user, though you'll have to check the edit history to see who was it.